# Custom function to retrieve results from mysql query then display

Tags: php, mysql

So I decided I wanted to add my own functions to my php code to make it a little cleaner. I wanted to make a function that carries out a SELECT query and return the results in an array. Then i want to be able to go through returned results. here is my current code:

displaying:

```
    $db = new Database("simplysql");
    $results = $db->fetchResults("SELECT * FROM users");


    ?>
```

fetching:

```
public function fetchResults($query) {
    $q = mysql_query($query);
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
}
```

I've tried using a foreach loop, but that didn't work well. It outputted the results 4 times.

Foreach code:

```
    foreach($results as $key=>$value) {
        print_r($results);
    }
```

This code outputs:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => root [password] => fc55917140c009fb20ed194b6a568fa2c7493071 [email] => duncanrp15@live.com ) 
Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => root [password] => fc55917140c009fb20ed194b6a568fa2c7493071 [email] => duncanrp15@live.com ) 
Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => root [password] => fc55917140c009fb20ed194b6a568fa2c7493071 [email] => duncanrp15@live.com ) 
Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => root [password] => fc55917140c009fb20ed194b6a568fa2c7493071 [email] => duncanrp15@live.com )
```

Even though there is only one record.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the `foreach` loop that you have tried?

Comment: Added to Original post.

Comment: How many record in table `users` ? What do you mean with "It outputted the results 4 times"? it show 4 rows?

Comment: anyway, you should using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Duncan . you can change your function code with `while loop` for getting an `array of associative records`

```
function fetchResults() {
    $q = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
     $resultrecord[] = $row;
    }
   return $resultRecord;
}
```

It will returns Array of your records..